# How can I make my copy and pasting work as intended

Tags: excel, vba

Hello all I did a macro in VBA that should check column D for the first empty cell then paste on that row but on column C, and when adding new info in the table it should take the first empty cell again, but it is replacing data, I don't check column C for first row because I have an filled cell midway, and if data were to replace that cell it should add a new row and avoid that.

```
`Sub CopyPasteToAnotherSheet()
  
  Dim sourceRange As Range
  Dim targetRange As Range
  Dim lastRow As Long
  Dim firstEmptyRow As Long
  
  Set sourceRange = Selection
  Set targetRange = Sheets("PARKING").Range("D18")
  
  lastRow = targetRange.End(xlDown).Row
  
  firstEmptyRow = Sheets("PARKING").Range("D" & lastRow).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  
  If lastRow = targetRange.Row Then
    targetRange.EntireRow.Insert
  End If
  
  If Sheets("PARKING").Range("C" & firstEmptyRow).Value <> "" Then
    firstEmptyRow = firstEmptyRow + 1
  End If
  
  Set targetRange = Sheets("PARKING").Range("C" & firstEmptyRow)
  
  sourceRange.Copy
  targetRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  
End Sub
`
```

I have tried to work with different search ranges but it keeps overwriting data.
also if it would keep numbering the newly added rows when adding new data it would be great I am clueless on how I should do that

Comment: Just curious ... Your targetRange is cell D18. Your lastRow value then > 18, say it's 20.
If from cell D1:D17 all have value BUT cell D3 and D5 are blank,  so your firstEmtpyRow value is 6 which is not an empty cell ? Please CMIIW. Also `If lastRow = targetRange.Row`, wouldn't the lastRow will never = targetRange.row ? Your targetRange is cell D18, so the targetRange.row is 18. And you get the value for lastRow using `targetRange.End(xlDown).Row` where the result will never be 18 but more than 18. Please CMIIW.

Comment: @karma so if I want to further down the line, create a macro that adds values underneath  the last occupied cell I should make a new macro where `Set targetRange = Sheets("PARKING").Range("D" & lastRow)`? regarding your questions of cells i'm not sure if i'm understanding you correctly, but my intention is to paste values into an empty table where the first empty row after the hearders is 18 and next week i need to add new values to it but I want them to start pasting from the first blank like before

Comment: Is this code in the workbook containing the worksheet `Parking`? If not, what is its name? In which column should the numbering (indexing) occur? Will you always be copying a single contiguous range e.g. `"A2:F10"` or not e.g. `"A2:F4,A6:F7,A10:F10"`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 the code is on the woorkbook that I have those sheets, regarding the range, column wise is always the same but row it may differ from time to time

Comment: @GonçaloRocha, I'm sorry I still cannot grasp your situation. You wrote : _VBA that should check column D for the first empty cell_.  (A) Are there going to be either one or more than one blank/empty cell in column D? Example : cell D1:D17 all have value but D5 and D10 are empty ---> so the first empty cell is cell D5, D10 is the second empty cell in column D. (B) did you mean the first cell in column D which is empty ? Example : cell D1:D17 all have value, D18 to the end of row column D are blank ---> so the first empty cell in column D is D18. Please CMIIW.

Comment: @karma it is like B) before D 18 is space reserved for headers information, D18 is the tenth blank cell from column D but i have to paste the info from that row

Comment: @GonçaloRocha, I'm very sorry as it is still difficult for me to understand your situation. If you can provide an image with data before run the sub, and the image with the expected result after run the sub, maybe I can understand it. Also, `Set sourceRange = Selection` ---> how is the selection ? always a one cell ? more than one cell ? in one column ? contiguous ? across some columns ?

Answer (score 0):

### Append Values

```vb
Sub AppendValues()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Append Values"
    Const DST_NAME As String = "PARKING"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "C18"
  
    If Selection Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no visible workbooks open
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Exit Sub ' not a range
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Selection
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = srg.Worksheet
        
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    If Not sws.Parent Is wb Then Exit Sub ' not in this workbook
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_NAME)
    If sws Is dws Then Exit Sub ' src. and dst. are the same worksheet
    If dws.FilterMode Then dws.ShowAllData ' '.Find' will fail if 'dws' filtered
    
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
    Dim dlCell As Range
    Set dlCell = dws.UsedRange.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If Not dlCell Is Nothing Then
        Set dfCell = dfCell.Offset(dlCell.Row - dfCell.Row + 1)
    End If
    
    Dim sarg As Range
    
    For Each sarg In srg.Areas
        dfCell.Resize(sarg.Rows.Count, sarg.Columns.Count).Value = sarg.Value
        Set dfCell = dfCell.Offset(sarg.Rows.Count)
    Next sarg
  
    MsgBox "Values appended to worksheet """ & DST_NAME & """.", _
        vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Really thankful for the help, my issue is that this is pasting to a template that has a value on cell C134 and C135 which i cannot overwrite, so basically it should paste to C18 onwards and when it should overwrite the content of cell C134 add a new line and keep inside the end of the template, sorry from any misconception from my behalf

Comment: That's great. Now you can ask another question.